# Processing stuck in step WriteSuccessfulRecords ... when using template Pub/Sub -> BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I keep getting this issue when I use a defined template. I am not sure what could be the issue.

As far as sdk: `Apache Beam SDK for Java 2.10.0`

```
Processing stuck in step WriteSuccessfulRecords/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables/StreamingWrite for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state finish
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:429)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
  at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:765)
  at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:829)
  at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.flushRows(StreamingWriteFn.java:130)
  at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.finishBundle(StreamingWriteFn.java:102)
  at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeFinishBundle(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Hi Askar interesting question, If you go to BigQuery WebUI and look at your query/job history do you see any useful information there which might guide you to what's going on? Also if you can share a bit more of your code and what schema are you targeting with which data?

Comment: This message doesn't necessarily mean that your pipeline is stuck. It may be that BigQuery is slow. Have you waited a few more minutes and still encountered that you continue to get the same message / your pipeline won't work?

Comment: I am using template that provided. I guess I under wrong impression that only need to specify table and when json object gets to Dataflow it will flat it and write to BQ.  I am still seeing issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems existing template require schema in order dataflow to work. After adding schema issue gone away.